# Extension to increase or decrease url parameter

Tags: google-chrome-extension, parameters, firefox-addon

Several years ago I used an extension that let you change a number parameter of the url you are visiting, by +1 or -1, or enter a number directly.

I mean, with this url:

```
www.foo.com/test?id=1
```

It could be changed to:

```
www.foo.com/test?id=2
```

Pressing the + button.

I tried searching everywhere and can't seem to find it.

I don't remember if it was on Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.

So, if anyone knows about this extension, or something similar, please let me know.

Comment: Do you need this to avoid Caching?

Comment: I'm pentesting, and I usually end up modifying parameters like that. Anyway, I think I will create my own Firefox addon to do this, will update later.